# size of IPv4 loopback address block

Tags: protocol-theory

According to [rfc3330](ftp://ftp.ripe.net/rfc/rfc3330.txt) the loopback block is 127.0.0.0/8:

```
   127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
   loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
   address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
   This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
   but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
   anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].
```

Is there a reason why this block is so huge? Are there occasions where any other addresses from 127.0.0.0/8 besides 127.0.0.1/8 are configured?

Comment: Some use IPs from the 127/8 block as "tiedowns" on new loopback interfaces on their routers, and then iBGP communicates on these IPs which are advertised as /32s out of some (or all) of the physical interfaces via the IGP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the times of clasful IP and 127.0.0.0 is an class-A network and therefore a /8 mask is assigned.

To answer the second part: Yes I've seen setups where more than 127.0.0.1 was used, e.g. for running multiple SMTP content filters on one host or multiple instances of a database server.

Note that for IPv6 you only have one loopback address ::1